# Preserving inline styling inside PRE TAG container

Tags: angular

I have a string like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html> <head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> <script src="script.js"></script> </head> <body> <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1> <pre><code>Some space <span style="background-color:#e6ffed;">then</span> more text.</code></pre> </body></html>
```

When i am rendering it inside angular, the text is rendering fine but inline style inside the span tag is missing.

how can i preserve inline style.

```
<pre [innerHTML]="rawhtml"></pre>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Due to security angular by default remove style or scripts tag present in string. To achieve this You have to use the `DomSantizer` provided by the angular. Just Inject the DomSantizer in your component then use the `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` method. You are good to go. For more details read the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/security#bypass-security-apis).

```
htmlToRender = this.santizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(rawhtml);

<pre [innerHTML]="htmlToRender "></pre>
```

Let me know If you are facing any issue.